# Allow windows to use more than 64GB of virtual memory

Tags: windows-10, virtual-memory, pagefile

I am running a process that will take a lot of memory (far more than I have physically), and I want it to finish.

Currently, when the committed memory amount reaches 64GB for the system, windows kills the process.

I set my pagefile so that there is a system managed one on one drive, and a separate one on a second drive, where the pagefile on the second drive goes from 1-64GB (just by itself).

Windows is still killing the process when the commit size gets to be 64GB.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: How much physical memory do you have?  How large is your page file set to be?

Comment: @Ramhound 24 GB, and system managed + 64000 MB (I know its not exactly 64GB, but it made no difference at all)

Comment: Is this also the case w/ "automatically manage" checked off? According to MS: "System-managed page files automatically grow up to three times physical memory or 4 GB (whichever is larger) when the system commit charge reaches 90 percent of the system commit limit. This assumes that enough free disk space is available to accommodate the growth." See as that you have enough disk space, it should work... Also maybe the page file can't span both drives for one process?

Comment: I started out with that box checked. 3x24 = 72GB, and it doesn't grow that far, it stops at 64GB. As to the last point, doesn't that defeat the whole point of virtual memory?

Comment: Yeah I agree, I was just throwing it out there as an idea. Other things - Have you checked the application/system areas of the event log to see if it's telling you why the process is being killed, or why the page file can't grow? Is it possible that there's a limitation / issue with the application itself?

Comment: Why is your system configure to place a page file on both the system and secondary drive (D)?

Comment: No good reason. C is an SSD, D is a spinning disk, and has gobs more space on it (1TB+). Should it matter?